# Named pipe race condition?

Tags: python, c, named-pipes, fifo, mkfifo

I have two processes one C and one python.  The C process spends its time passing data to a named pipe which the python process then reads.  Should be pretty simple and it works fine when I'm passing data (currently a time stamp such as "Mon Aug 19 18:30:59 2013") once per second.

Problems occur when I take out the sleep(1); command in the C process.  When there's no one second delay the communication quickly gets screwed up.  The python process will read more than one message or report that it has read data even though its buffer is empty.  At this point the C process usually bombs.

Before I go posting any sample code I'm wondering if I need to implement some sort of synchronisation on both sides.  Like maybe telling the C process not to write to the fifo if it's not empty?

The C process opens the named pipe write only and the python process opens as read only.

Both processes are intended to be run as loops.  The C process continually reads data as it comes in over a USB port and the python process takes each "message" and parses it before sending it to a SQL Db.

If I'm going to be looking at up to 50 messages per second, will named pipes be able to handle that level of transaction rate?  The size of each transaction is relatively small (20 bytes or so) but the frequency makes me wonder if I should be looking at some other form of inter-process communication such as shared memory?

Any advice appreciated.  I can post code if necessary but at the moment I'm just wondering if I should be syncing between the two processes somehow.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of how the communication gets screwed up? What do you mean the C process bombs? Segfaults? Does it give any output when it bombs?

Comment: Funny thing about the C process - the write statement for the moment is just in a basic while(1) infinite loop.  When it crashes it just returns to the shell prompt...no segfaults.  I found that I could recreate this behaviour on the C process by CTRL-Cing the python process.  I would have thought that the C process would just return to a blocking write state.

Comment: I replaced the sleep(1) with a for loop that effectively allows the C process to do around 50 writes per second.  This seems to be working OK but I'd like to leave this running for at least 48 hours to be confident that.

Comment: I also made the message fixed length - 34 bytes - for example "000146920-Mon Aug 19 22:03:45 2013".  The 9-digit number is just a counter which is incremented with each write.  So now the python program is just reading 34 bytes per read operation.  Even with this fixed length solution if I don't have any delay (sleep or for loop) the processes quickly get messed up.

Comment: I guess it may be getting a SIGPIPE which causes the process to terminate.

Comment: I think the root cause was because on the python side, I was opening, reading and closing the named pipe all in the loop.  I guess if the C process was writing to the named pipe at the same time that python process closed the pipe then the SIGPIPE would have been generated.  So, I have moved the open and close outside of the read loop and will continue testing but looks good at the moment.

Comment: When you moved the open/close outside the loop, did you also remove the sleep from the C program?

Answer (score 2):

A pipe is a stream.

The number of `write()` calls on the sender side does not necessarily need to correspond to the number of `read()`s on the receiver's side.

Try to implement some sort of synchronisation protocol.

If sending plain text you could do so for example by adding new-lines between each token and make the receiver read up until one of such is found.

Alternatively you could prefix each data sent, with a fixed length number representing the amount of the data to come. The receiver then can parse this format.

Comment: Very true.  Using a delimiter is a good idea.  So instead of reading the entire contents of the named pipe each time I just read a character at a time until I reach the delimiter?

Comment: Hmm, the fixed length message also has merit - it would certainly be quicker to read.  Might be worth the overhead of wasted (padded) bytes.  Thanks alk - this gives me a couple of options to play with.

Comment: @dermur - that is one way of doing it.

Comment: @dermur: I did not ment to say fixed lenght message, but only fixed length message header, giving the number of byte of the message payload being sent afterwards.